# Find students who have registered all course that a specific student did

Tags: sql

I have three tables: student, course, and registration. I want to use select statement (single query) to find the **ID(s_id)** of students who registered all the courses that student with S_ID:1 did. The tables are as below:

Student (s_id, s_name)

1, John

2, Jason

3, Tom

Course (c_id, c_name)

1, Math

2, Science

3, Sport

Registration (s_id, c_id)

1,1

1,2

2,1

2,3

3,1

3,2

3,3

In this simple case, it would be student No.3 since he also registered course No.1 and 2 (student No.2 did not register course No.2). Please help me with this question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? Have you been taught what an analytic/window function is?

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
Select * from student where id in (select s_id fom Registration where c_id in (select c_id from Registration where s_id = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The query of Caius Jard is right when (s_id,c_is) is unique, but if one student can register in a course multiple time, you should change the code as below :

```
SELECT s_id 
FROM registration
WHERE c_id IN (SELECT c_id FROM registration WHERE s_id = 1) AND s_id <> 1
GROUP BY s_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration WHERE s_id = 1 GROUP BY c_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using basic sql:

```
SELECT s_id 
FROM registration
WHERE c_id IN (SELECT c_id FROM registration WHERE s_id = 1) AND s_id <> 1
GROUP BY s_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration WHERE s_id = 1)
```

This gets the list of courses 1 is registered for (1,2) then gets a list of all other records where the course is 1 or 2. At this point student 2 will have been selected, but then we group and count the records we have. Student 2 will only appear once, so he fails the HAVING test, which essentially demands that a student appears in the list twice. Because student 3 is registered for 3 courses including 1 and 2, he will appear in the results twice (once for 1, once for 2) before he is grouped and counted. When counted his count is 2, which matches the demanded count in the HAVING

Answer (score -1):

One method is to generate all combinations of the courses you care about for each student.  Then use a `left join` to match these to the courses that actually exist, and check that all courses are accounted for:

```
select s.s_id
from student s cross join
     (select distinct c_id
      from registration r
      where r.s_id = 2
     ) c left join
     registration r
     on r.c_id = c.c_id and r.s_id = s.s_id
group by s.s_id
having count(*) = count(r.s_id);
```